# Can we define a node's inner sep value with relative units in terms of the in-scope font key value?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles

Very often I find myself defining styles for various drawing annotations. This is great for structuring figures. There is, however, a minor thing I hope I can improve. This stems from the fact that any relative dimensions (units of `ex` or `em`) are always interpreted by Ti*k*Z relative to the font size in effect at the "level" of the `tikzpicture` code itself.

If I need to change the font size of one annotation by using `font=\tiny`, for instance, I also need to manually tweak the `inner sep` value, because the default (or whatever is specified in the style definition) does not always look so nice with the changed font size.

If I could set up style definitions so that the value of `font` is used as the basis for any `ex` or `em` dimensions in `inner sep`, this problem could take care of itself. I would also consider a solution where the `font` and `inner sep` values are specified as arguments to a style if it allows this limitation to be overcome.

Here is an MWE:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\tikzset{
  my inner sep/.style={inner sep=#1}, % how to define this?
  every node/.style={anchor=south west},
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[my inner sep=0.2em] (A) {A};
  \node[font=\tiny,my inner sep=0.2em] (B) {B};
  \foreach \node in {A,B} {
    \draw[blue,line width=0.01pt] % just to show the baselines
      (\node.south west) |- (\node.base) -| (\node.north east);
  }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The current output is:

[image]

The blue hairlines are just to show the baseline of each node. As shown, the baselines are the same distance from the bottom of the nodes. A suitable definition of `my inner sep` will produce output with text `B` shifted down and to the left of its position shown above, because `0.2em` in `\tiny` is less than `0.2em` in `\normalsize`.

Is such a goal possible with the current Ti*k*Z architecture/order of operations? If so, how can it be done?

Comment: I assume that you know that if you put `\tiny` within the scope, you get the right result.

Comment: @cfr: whoops, yes, I just had the scope in there for testing. Yes, the font setting in effect during the code (Is there a better way to express this? It's odd because there's really no "text" typeset there.) does apply correctly, but I want to base it off the font in-scope for the node text itself.

Comment: If you have a style `my tiny/.code={\tiny}` then you can say `\node [my tiny, inner sep=0.2em] ...`. So maybe you are trying to adapt the wrong thing? Maybe you want `my font` rather than `my inner sep`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From `PGF 3.0` there is a `node font` key which sets the font for the node *and* is used as the font in node dimension calculations using `em` and `ex`. See section `17.4.2` ("Text Parameters: Font") in the `PGF 3.0` manual.

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=5]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={fill=gray!50, anchor=south west}]
  \node [inner sep=1em]                  at (0,0) (A) {A};
  \node [font=\tiny,      inner sep=1em] at (0,1) (B) {B};
  \node [node font=\tiny, inner sep=1em] at (0,2) (C) {C};
  \foreach \n in {A,B,C} {
    \draw[red, very thin, <->] (\n.base west) -- (\n.base east);
    \draw[red, very thin, <->] (\n.text |- \n.south) -- (\n.text |- \n.north);
  }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Wow, much simpler than I thought. :-) Thanks Mark!

Comment: Are there places it's preferable to use `font` instead of `node font` or any pitfalls I should be aware of? (Other than the `split` case discussed in the manual.)

Comment: @PaulGessler I don't know actually. I _think_ that `font` key retains the old functionality just for compatibility, so that older code using `em` and `ex` produces the same effect with the new PGF version.